# Padding statement transition with background and image and text?

Tags: html, css

**[Note: scroll to the bottom to see exactly what I need]**

I am trying to do some kind of simple decoration to my image in HTML. The decoration is to show information about the image with sliding animation only when hovered with the mouse. I tried to make it, but at some point I couldn't figure out how to put the text information in the slider. I tried to make `<div>` tag to put the text, but it's shows only under the image. While in my situation, I want it to be perfectly behind it.

Here is how I made them:

```css
img.img1, div.img1 {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    border: 10px solid rgb(0,0,150);
    background: rgb(0,0,150);
    padding-right: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
}

img.img1:hover, div.img1:hover {
    padding-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img class="img1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/34/b5/86/34b58689b0870284621a661a2c538652.png">

<div class="img1">
  <p>Name: Eren Yeager</p>
  <p>Age: 20 y.o</p>
  <p>Anime: Attack On Titan</p>
  <p>Height: 195cm</p>
  <p>Living in: Shiganshina District</p>
</div>
```

In the script above, I don't want the slider to just slide without the text. I want it to slide and sliding the text with it so it'll look like this:

```css
img.img1, div.img1 {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    border: 10px solid rgb(0,0,150);
    background: rgb(0,0,150);
    margin-left: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
}

img.img1:hover {
    padding-right: 150px;
}

div.img1:hover {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img class="img1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/34/b5/86/34b58689b0870284621a661a2c538652.png">

<div class="img1">
  <p>Name: Eren Yeager</p>
  <p>Age: 20 y.o</p>
  <p>Anime: Attack On Titan</p>
  <p>Height: 195cm</p>
  <p>Living in: Shiganshina District</p>
</div>
```

In the end. What I want is:

1. **The image information is hiding behind the image (the user can't see them).**
2. **Once the user hover over the image, the information will slide from behind the image.**

**Example:**

```css
img.img1, div.img1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 10px solid rgb(0,0,150);
    background: rgb(0,0,150);
    margin-left: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
}

img.img2, div.img2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 10px solid rgb(0,0,150);
    background: rgb(0,0,150);
    margin-left: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
}
```

```html
<img class="img1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/34/b5/86/34b58689b0870284621a661a2c538652.png">
<br>
<br>

<p>When the user hover:</p>
<br>
<br>



<img class="img2" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/34/b5/86/34b58689b0870284621a661a2c538652.png">

<div class="img2">
  <p>Name: Eren Yeager</p>
  <p>Age: 20 y.o</p>
  <p>Anime: Attack On Titan</p>
  <p>Height: 195cm</p>
  <p>Living in: Shiganshina District</p>
</div>
```

If I needed to use `JavaScript` to do it, then it's fine I'll use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put them in a wrapper

Then by using `position:absolute;` on the `<div class="img2">` as well as giving it `top:0; right:0;` will make the info div cling unto the upper-right corner of the wrapper so that whenever the wrapper extends to the right, the `div.img2` will move to the right as well

Next give the `img.img2` a `z-index:10;` to make it float/appear on top of everything else;

Finally assign the `:hover` to the wrapper. Add `padding-left:150px;` with a `transition: padding .5s` and your done.

[Note from [Liqui Kal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15622377/liqui-kal): If the background does not fit perfectly behind the image, then change the statement `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline-flex;`]

We can use inline-flex / inline-grid to center the image using `align-items:center` to vertically align the image but we can't justify it because when justified to the center, the image will move along the expansion of the parent div. - [StepPen-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10366783/steppen-codes)

```js
let radioBtn = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')

for (let btn of radioBtn) btn.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--text-align', event.target.value)
})
```

```css
:root {
  --text-align: left;
}

.imgWCap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 150);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.imgWCap:hover {
  padding-right: 140px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 150);
}

.img2 {
  padding: 10px;
}

img.img2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

div.img2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: var(--text-align);
  /*Here is the the text align at work;*/
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
HOVER OVER THE PICTURE <br>
<div class="imgWCap">
  <img class="img2" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/34/b5/86/34b58689b0870284621a661a2c538652.png">

  <div class="img2">
    <p>Name: Eren Yeager</p>
    <p>Age: 20 y.o</p>
    <p>Anime: Attack On Titan</p>
    <p>Height: 195cm</p>
    <p>Living in: Shiganshina District</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>Pick the text-alignment that you need.
<form>
  <label for=left>Left</label><input id=left name=align type=radio value=left>
  <label for=center>Center</label><input id=center name=align type=radio value=center>
  <label for=right>right</label><input id=right name=align type=radio value=right>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it worked. But I got a small problem. It's not perfectly behind the the image, also it's seems like I can't move the text at all. `text-align` statement seems to have no effect to the text because I distributed a `position` statement with `top: 0;` and `right: 0;`. Any ideas, @steppen ?

Comment: Can you show me? I tried that, but it's not centering.

Comment: I added the option to choose text-align in the code above check it.

Comment: That's weird, it works perfect, but only only on vertical statement. I removed the vertical statement so it stopped centering. The text only center when it's vertical not horizontal. But I changed my mind, I did a separated box behind the image to move when you hover it instead of padding in the same image it gave me much more control to the styles. Anyways, thank you so much for putting effort in answering me. (Side question: are you from Iraq? @steppen ).